# How can I write line numbers inside boxed code

Tags: lists, pseudocode

I am trying to show a code-piece inside a box. I was wondering is it possible to has its line numbers inside the box as well, shifting code little to the right?

I have following code:

```tex
\expandafter\def\csname ver@fixltx2e.sty\endcsname{}
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc\usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
    \usepackage{cite}
\fi
\ifCLASSINFOpdf\else\fi
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\input{solidity-highlighting.tex}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lstinputlisting[label={fig:withdraw}, belowskip=0
    \baselineskip, basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily, frame=tlrb, rulecolor=\color{black}]{hello.sol}
\end{document}
```

hello.sol:

```
function hello() public returns (bool) {
    uint256 amount = 100
    return amount * 100
    return true;
}
```

and [solidity-highlighting.tex](https://github.com/s-tikhomirov/solidity-latex-highlighting/blob/master/solidity-highlighting.tex)

output (its line numbers exceed the left limit of the column as well):

[image]

wanted output (best I can do using paint):

[image]

Comment: Use the option `framexleftmargin` to include the numbers

Comment: `framexleftmargin ` seemed work fine but it exceeds the left side of the column ruler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I warmly suggest `tcolorbox`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.sol}
function hello() public returns bool {
    uint256 amount = 100
    return amount * 100
    return true;
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
  \usepackage{cite}
\fi

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\definecolor{verylightgray}{rgb}{.97,.97,.97}

\newtcbinputlisting{\inputlisting}[2][]{%
   listing file={#2},
   top=0pt,
   left=16pt,
   bottom=0pt,
   right=8pt,
   colback=verylightgray,
   colframe=black,
   listing only,
   breakable,
   sharp corners,
   boxrule=0.2pt,
   listing options={#1},
}

\lstdefinelanguage{Solidity}{
  keywords=[1]{% generic keywords including crypto operations
    anonymous, assembly, assert, balance, break, call, callcode, case,
    catch, class, constant, continue, constructor, contract, debugger,
    default, delegatecall, delete, do, else, emit, event, experimental,
    export, external, false, finally, for, function, gas, if, implements,
    import, in, indexed, instanceof, interface, internal, is, length,
    library, log0, log1, log2, log3, log4, memory, modifier, new, payable,
    pragma, private, protected, public, pure, push, require, return,
    returns, revert, selfdestruct, send, solidity, storage, struct,
    suicide, super, switch, then, this, throw, transfer, true, try,
    typeof, using, value, view, while, with, addmod, ecrecover, keccak256,
    mulmod, ripemd160, sha256, sha3
  },
  keywordstyle=[1]\color{blue}\bfseries,
  keywords=[2]{% types; money and time units
    address, bool, byte, bytes, bytes1, bytes2, bytes3, bytes4, bytes5,
    bytes6, bytes7, bytes8, bytes9, bytes10, bytes11, bytes12, bytes13,
    bytes14, bytes15, bytes16, bytes17, bytes18, bytes19, bytes20, bytes21,
    bytes22, bytes23, bytes24, bytes25, bytes26, bytes27, bytes28, bytes29,
    bytes30, bytes31, bytes32, enum, int, int8, int16, int24, int32, int40,
    int48, int56, int64, int72, int80, int88, int96, int104, int112, int120,
    int128, int136, int144, int152, int160, int168, int176, int184, int192,
    int200, int208, int216, int224, int232, int240, int248, int256, mapping,
    string, uint, uint8, uint16, uint24, uint32, uint40, uint48, uint56,
    uint64, uint72, uint80, uint88, uint96, uint104, uint112, uint120,
    uint128, uint136, uint144, uint152, uint160, uint168, uint176, uint184,
    uint192, uint200, uint208, uint216, uint224, uint232, uint240, uint248,
    uint256, var, void, ether, finney, szabo, wei, days, hours, minutes,
    seconds, weeks, years},
  keywordstyle=[2]\color{teal}\bfseries,
  keywords=[3]{% environment variables
    block, blockhash, coinbase, difficulty, gaslimit, number, timestamp,
    msg, data, gas, sender, sig, value, now, tx, gasprice, origin
  },
  keywordstyle=[3]\color{violet}\bfseries,
  identifierstyle=\color{black},
  sensitive=false,
  comment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  commentstyle=\color{gray}\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]"
}

\lstset{
  language=Solidity,
  backgroundcolor=\color{verylightgray},
  extendedchars=true,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showspaces=false,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\footnotesize,
  numbersep=9pt,
  tabsize=2,
  breaklines=true,
  showtabs=false,
  captionpos=b
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\inputlisting{\jobname.sol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to remove extra space (newline) at top and bottom ?

Comment: @alper One should look more deeply in the manual, but I believe that giving negative values for `top` and `bottom` achieves the goal.

Comment: Thanks is it also possible to read the file contents from a file path?

Comment: @alper With the same rules as for `\lstinputlisting`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the option `framexleftmargin` to include the numbers:

```
\expandafter\def\csname ver@fixltx2e.sty\endcsname{}
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc\usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
    \usepackage{cite}
\fi
\ifCLASSINFOpdf\else\fi
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\input{solidity-highlighting.tex}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lstinputlisting[framexleftmargin=5mm,label={fig:withdraw}, belowskip=0
    \baselineskip, basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily, frame=tlrb, rulecolor=\color{black}]{hello.sol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked but left side exceeds the column ruler please see output: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/b3824a09a5819477fecab17b1931d004?permalink_comment_id=4154616#gistcomment-4154616 // is it possible to shift it to right to prevent it, or somehow fit into column

Comment: @alper - You can adjust with the option `xleftmargin=`. Maybe you have to experiment with the values make the box align smoothly

Comment: When I used `xleftmargin=` now right side exceeds the column limit

Comment: Then you have to make the box narrower (try `xrightmargin`). You can find all available commands in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf)

Comment: Instead of manually giving `xleftmargin` and `xrightmargin` values , can it forces the find best optimal value to be narrowed?