# How can I remove extra white space of a caption when listing wrap inside a figure?

Tags: captions, listings

I want to wrap `listing` inside a figure. But when I do that there is plent white space in between its caption. How can I remove extra white space of Figure's caption when listing wrap inside a figure?

I have following code, [origin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/642980/127048):

```tex
\expandafter\def\csname ver@fixltx2e.sty\endcsname{}
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc\usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
    \usepackage{cite}
\fi
\ifCLASSINFOpdf\else\fi
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{listings, xcolor}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
hello world hello world hello world hello world
\begin{figure}[htp]
        \lstinputlisting[frame=tlrb, rulecolor=\color{black}]{hello.sol}
        \caption{hello world.}
\end{figure}
hello world hello world hello world hello world
\end{document}
```

hello.sol:

```
function hello() public returns (bool) {
    uint256 amount = 100
    return amount * 100
    return true;
}
```

output:

[image]

Here you can see that font of the caption is smaller and there is plenty white space generated on top and bottom of the caption. Is it possible to remove those?

When I have caption inside `listing` if I can replace `Listing` with `Figure` it works for me as well.

Comment: Sound like you don't want `figure` at all, what about [cross referencing - Label and caption without float - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/label-and-caption-without-float) ?

Comment: Will this approach replace `Listing` tag with `Figure` tag? I am not sure would it be ok to refere it as Figure though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MWE shouldn't rely on external files. If possible, please provide a standalone code that can be copy-pasted.

However, a possible solution is to use the caption feature of `listings`, instead of relying on a figure. Remove the `figure` environment as well as the `\caption` command and then:

```
\lstinputlisting[caption={hello world.}, captionpos=b, frame=tlrb, rulecolor=\color{black}]{hello.sol}
```

Comment: No problem, and thanks for the update. Does my answer above provide a satisfactory result?

Comment: The tag is `Listing` is it possible to replace it as `Figure`? and have it bottom of the figure instead of top of it

Comment: The `listings` documentation mentions the `captionpos` option. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: As for replacing "listings" with "figure", I find it a bit strange to name "figure" something that isn't a figure... But, again according to `listings` documentation, you can just redefine `\lstlistingname` for this.

Comment: You are right :-) In the paper I was referring `in Figure~\ref{_listing}` but I should do `in Listing` instead seems like its the right way to do it

Comment: I don't use it myself, but you might want to have a look at package `cleveref` which handles that sort of detail automatically.

Comment: Can also `[ht]` applied to listing? When the listing is botto of the page it kind of splitted half to other column, where `[ht]` of the figure was preventing that

Comment: Sorry I removed my last comment because I misread your answer. The solution is given page 29 of the documentation, option `float`.